# Should i use array_diff_assoc or ===?

Tags: php, comparison, equals-operator

I'm trying to compare two arrays to see if they are sorted or not.
What is the difference between array_diff_assoc and comparing two arrays with the === operator?
Are they the same thing?

For example

```
$arr_a
$arr_b

array_diff_assoc($arr_a, $arr_b)
```

Is the same as

```
$arr_a === $arr_b
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example tells us that these are **different** methods:

```
$a = ['t' => 2, 'p' => 3];
$b = ['p' => 3, 't' => 2];
var_dump($a === $b); // false, arrays are not identical                
var_dump(array_diff_assoc($a, $b));  
// array(0) {} - means that there's no difference between these arrays
// they have same keys with same values, but in different orders 
// and for `===` order is important
```

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of differences.

`array_diff_assoc` return an array that contains element in a not found in b.

```
$a = [ 1 => 'first' , 2 , 3];
$b = [ 1 => 'first' , 2 , 4 , 3];
var_dump(array_diff_assoc($a,$b) // [ 3 => 3 ] because in a element 3 key is 3 and in b element 3 is 4.
```

Also `array_diff_assoc` does not work with multidimensional array. For more information visit the documentation [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

`$a === $b` return true or false based on key/value pair comparison in addition to the order of the element and it can work with multidimensional array. So if you need a true or false comparison use

```
$a === $b // if order and type is important 
$a == $b  // if order and type are not important
1 === '1' // false 
1 == '1'  //true
```

For more information visit the documentation [Array Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Answer (score 1):

It should also be stated that `array_diff_assoc()` will be making string comparisons.  This further enforces the earlier insights, that these technique are definitely different.

> Two values from key => value pairs are considered equal only if (string) $elem1 === (string) $elem2 . In other words a strict check takes place so the string representations must be the same. <sub>[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)</sub>

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dttb5))

```
$arr_a = [1,   false, null, 0,     '0'];
$arr_b = ['1', null,  0,    false, 0];

var_export(
    array_diff_assoc($arr_a, $arr_b)
);

echo "\n---\n";

$arr_a = [1,   false, '0'];
$arr_b = ['1', null,  0];

var_export(
    array_diff_assoc($arr_a, $arr_b)
);

echo "\n---\n";

var_export($arr_a === $arr_b);
```

Output:

```
array (
  2 => NULL,
  3 => 0,
)
---
array (
)
---
false
```